# How can we use expressions such as substring(...) in jsrender

Tags: jsrender

I have a para with 500 characters.I want to insert ...  after 155th character and should hide the other characters. If anyone know the syntax and usage of substring in jsrender. guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsRender lets you use expressions within tags.

See the doc topics such as *[Tag syntax](http://www.jsviews.com/#tagsyntax)*, or *[Paths and expressions](http://www.jsviews.com/#paths)*.

You can write things like:

```
{{:myfield.substring(0, 155)}}
```

or

```
{{:myfield.substring(0, 155) + '...'}}
```

or (for your complete scenario):

```
{{:myfield.subscript(0, 155) + (myfield.length>155 ? '...' : '')}}
```

Given the complexity of that expression, it would be cleaner to encapsulate it in a helper (http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers) or custom tag (http://www.jsviews.com/#tags):

For example you could define a helper:

```
$.views.helpers("trimLength", function(value, maxLength) {
  if (maxLength && value.length > maxLength) {
    return value.substring(0, maxLength ) + "...";
  }
  return value;
})
```

and then write:

```
{{:~trimLength(myfield, 155)}}
```

or define a custom tag:

```
$.views.tags("trim", function(value) {
  var maxLength = this.tagCtx.props.maxLength;
  if (maxLength && value.length > maxLength) {
    return value.substring(0, maxLength ) + "...";
  }
  return value;
})
```

and then write:

```
{{trim myfield maxLength=155 /}}
```

Comment: Why do i get the error like this,while rendering the template..JsRender Error: Unknown template: "#ProgramDetails"

Comment: That error is because you are presumably writing something like $.templates("ProgramDetails").render(...) but you don't actually have an element with id "ProgramDetails" - so it can't find the template you are trying to render.